# manage two github repositories simultaneously

Tags: git, github

I have a client and internal repository. I want to push code from internal repository to client repository in such a way that all of the new code from internal repository will come to my branch in client repository and this branch is not to show the history from my internal repository. I want to make a bash file which will execute all the commands in orders to help me automating all of the steps included. Any input will be highly appreciated.

As far as git remote add remote-name remote-url is concerned, I have done that part but I am more worried about the history of my internal repository.

How can I make a commit in client repo branch from internal repo branch without showing the history of internal repository?

Comment: Welcome to you Adil, but this is a (the?) Q&A website. What's the *question* here?

Comment: Each repo is independent. You may have to write scripts to do what you want

Comment: @RomainValeri, I have updated the post. kindly share any input.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I want to write a script to manage git commit in my branch of client's repo from internal repo branch and removing history as well.

Comment: Ok. That's a lot of requirements. Do you have a specific question regarding them?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, I am just figuring out the way to push code in such a way that the history of internal repo commits will not appear in PR of client repo.

Comment: Please be aware that git pushes commits, which contain files.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, I am aware. But when I pull a branch from internal repository. all of its commits along with messages come to my branch of client repo as well. I just want to pull in such a way that the only files are fetched from internal repo. the history should not be fetched.